# How to filter data using Dropdown and Partial View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Ok.What I am trying to do here in MVC application is display a table Names, Country etc in a view which does work. Now, I am trying to filter it using a dropdown. The dropdown does get populated. The problem is my action result is not getting called from jQuery. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is my model

```
public partial class tblDropdownFilter
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 

   public ActionResult Index()
   {       
        DropdownFilterSampleEntities dfse = new DropdownFilterSampleEntities();
        ViewBag.Names = new SelectList(dfse.tblDropdownFilters, "ID", "Name");
        var a = dfse.tblDropdownFilters.ToList();
        return View(a);
    }

    public ActionResult GetNames(int id)
    {
        DropdownFilterSampleEntities dfse = new DropdownFilterSampleEntities();
        var a = dfse.tblDropdownFilters.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToList();
        return PartialView("_GetNames",a);
    }
}
```

Here is my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<SampleDropdownFilter.Models.tblDropdownFilter>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var items in Model)
        { 
         <tr>
        <td>
            @items.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @items.Country
        </td>
        <td>
            @items.Birthdate
        </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@Html.DropDownList("Names", "Select a name")

<div id="target"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Names").change(function () {
            type: 'get',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNames")',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { id: $(this).val() },
            success: function (result) {                   
                $("#target").html(result);
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally, here is my partial view. The name is _GetNames.cshtml

```
@model SampleDropdownFilter.Models.tblDropdownFilter

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Country)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Check the console. It also looks like your ajax call in $("#Names").change(function () { is missing its first line.

Comment: I am not getting any error at all. I put a break point on action method of partial view and when I change dropdown option, it simply doesn't get called.

Comment: Ok, I was missing $.ajax in first line. I fixed that. It still isn't hitting the breakpoint I set on action method.

Comment: Anyone? Need a bit if help here

Answer (score 0):

@frozenmirage Try this in your script..

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#Names").change(function () {

            var myVal = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Home")?id=' + myVal,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#target').html(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("Failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: changed it to a post. You could do get with a query string but if you're passing the data that way i normally use POST.

Comment: Is it really necessary that the action method which renders partial view must be  HttpPost?

Comment: No it's not you can do this with GET methods easily. Can edit my answer to reflect that.. one moment.

Comment: The thing is for some reason, with Get method it is not working.