# How to undo pending changes in MVC Textboxfor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to have a Html.Textboxfor in Edit form. The textbox will be mapped with data coming from model. I also want to have a button to undo changes and revert back to what was mapped before.

How do I implement this?

Comment: This might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925441/reset-button-to-default-value-for-input-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@frozenmirage A few different ways you can do this. You might try loading the initial value into a hidden input and grab it when your 'undo' button is clicked.. like this.

Razor

```
<input type="hidden" id="TextBoxValue" value="@Model.yourtextboxattributename" />
```

Script

```
$('#undo').click(function(){
    var value = $('#TextBoxValue').val();
    $('#yourtextboxattributename').val("");
    $('#yourtextboxattributename').val(value);
});
```

Comment: Does the Hiddenfor have to be in Beginform?

Comment: No and it doesn't have to be a hiddenfor either. It could be a hidden div or anything like that. But if you changed it from an input to a div you would need to change the way you get the value in jQuery.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly.

Comment: Basically stuff the value somewhere on the page when the page is being loaded... It does not need to be a hidden input. It does not need to be in the form. It can be anything that isn't displayed. Once the page is rendered, and they make changes and decide to click 'undo', just grab the value from where you stuffed it with javascript...

Comment: That has to be in the controller right since I am having TextBoxFor?

Comment: Here. Try this. I'll change my answer... paste the html right below your textboxfor and then put the script at the bottom.

Comment: Any chance you can help me with this one? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496438/how-to-filter-data-using-dropdown-and-partial-view?noredirect=1#comment58685178_35496438